# Sed replace "stringvariable" with "string/variable"

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I am trying to use sed in order to replace

blah.org$VARIABLE to blah.org/$VARIABLE

I can do it without using a variable with:

```
sed 's,orgSOMETHING,org/SOMETHING/,g' < file
```

but when I try

```
sed 's,org$VARIABLE,org/$VARIABLE/,g' < file
```

it doesn't work...sorry for dumb question

Comment: Variables are not replaced inside single quotes. Use double-quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dollar symbol.

```
sed 's,org\$VARIABLE,org/\$VARIABLE/,g'  file
```

If `$VARIABLE` is actually a variable name then use double quotes.

```
sed "s,org$VARIABLE,org/$VARIABLE/,g"  file
```